# ZF2 console error - Get was unable to fetch or create an instance for ViewRenderer

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, command-line-interface

I have the problem with doctrine console. I have a MailServiceFactory.php containing this code:

```
namespace Application\Service;

use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class MailServiceFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $I_render = $serviceLocator->get('ViewRenderer');

        $a_config = $serviceLocator->get('config');

        return new MailService($I_render, $a_config);
    }
}
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class MailServiceFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $I_render = $serviceLocator->get('ViewRenderer');

        $a_config = $serviceLocator->get('config');

        return new MailService($I_render, $a_config);
    }
}
```

and all functions works, but when i execute the `vendor/bin/doctirne-module` I get the error below:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException' with message
>   'Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create
>   an instance for ViewRenderer' in
>   /Users/Daniele/Apps/corradini.com/www/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:529

Why i'm getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get `ViewRenderer` directly from `ServiceLocator` on console requests because its not in stage since request is not an `HttpRequest`.

Instead of `ViewRenderer`, you can easily try to passing a `PhpRenderer` instance to your service and render a `ViewModel` using that. For example:

```
use Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer;

class MailServiceFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $renderer = new PhpRenderer();
        $a_config = $serviceLocator->get('config');

        return new MailService($renderer, $a_config);
    }
```

Now in your MailService:

```
use Zend\View\Renderer\RendererInterface;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class MailService
{
   protected $renderer;

   public function __construct(RendererInterface $renderer, $config)
   {
       $this->renderer = $renderer;
       // set your config etc..
   }

   public function fooMethod()
   {
       $model = new ViewModel();
       $model->setTemplate('path/to/template.phtml');
       $result = $this->renderer->render($model);
       // The $result contains rendered html markup
   }
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks foozy now doctrine console funciton! but the i can't read the tempalte for render mail.

```
My tempate is locatend in module/Application/view/email/template.phtml
```

In my module.config.php there is configuration:

```
'template_path_stack' => array(
            'application' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
```

And error:

```
Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template "email/template.phtml"; resolver could not resolve to a file
```

where mistake ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after I added a view_manager config to the console config. The solution is to just pull the renderer from the ViewManager:

```
$renderer = $serviceLocator->get('ViewManager')->getRenderer();
```

This will also register the ViewRenderer service, so any calls to `get('ViewRenderer')` after this should work too.

Answer (score 0):

in ZF3 also a TemplateMapResolver can help you to fix some issues like:
"PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template"

```
$resolver = new \Zend\View\Resolver\TemplateMapResolver();
$resolver->setMap([
    'mailTemplate' => __DIR__ . '/../../view/email/testmail.phtml'
]);
$renderer->setResolver($resolver);
$viewContent = new \Zend\View\Model\ViewModel($contentArray);
$viewContent->setTemplate('mailTemplate');
```